# ng-show expression: comparing multiple strings using ||

Tags: angularjs

Can someone please explain why this works:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <span ng-hide="fruit.type == 'apple' || fruit.type == 'banana'">
        {{fruit.type}} 
    </span>
</div>
```

Renders:

```
pear lemon
```

But this doesn't:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <span ng-hide="fruit.type == 'apple' || 'banana'">
        {{fruit.type}} 
    </span>
</div>
```

Renders:

```
// nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript (and most languages I know), comparisons aren't communicable. For every comparison (in this case equality), you unfortunately need a full statement.

In `fruit.type == 'apple' || 'banana'`,
1. `fruit.type == 'apple'` is evaluated.
2. *After* that, it `||` compares the result of that to `'banana'`, which in Javascript is a *truthy* value (`''` is the only "falsy" string, all other strings are "truthy").

In essence, you end up with `fruit.type == 'apple' || TRUE`, which will always trigger `ng-hide`.

Comment: Ooooh, got'cha. Thanks, Harris.

Comment: As a side suggestion/tip, you can define your own [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) for `ng-repeat`, so that you don't iterate over particular elements in the first place. The way you do it now doesn't seem particularly problematic, but it's always good to know about tools dedicated to a particular task, and using this one would be a minor expense to make every use of it in the future easier.

Answer (score 0):

in this case its a bad expression fruit.type == 'apple' || 'banana' 
    || are used in javascript for "OR" and define a default value to a variable when some reference values is undefined or null for example:

```
var name = null || "mottaman85";

consolog.log(name);
"mottaman85"

function test(nombreV){
 var name = nombreV || "mottaman85"; 
console.log(name)
}

test();
"mottaman85"
```